# What is the best ad balance for Adsense?

Tags: adsense

I have currently set my Adsense ad balance to 40%-60%, which is the ideal percentage ratio to enhance earning?

And if you are a user of adsense yourself, then what ratio have you selected?

I have tried tweaking with it, but nothing seems to work for a long time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Then where can i ask questions related to AdSense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every website has a different sweet spot in terms of ad balance, it will not be useful for other publishers to tell you their ad balance setting. There is no single 'right' setting.

However, to answer your question, the best you can do is use the 'Experiment' function from within your AdSense Ad Balance interface.

Setup several Ad Balance experiments in order to find out the best ad balance for your site.

Comment: Is it Program related problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Program Related". For Fahad to improve his ad balance setting, the best method is to use the AdSense built-in 'Experiment' function in order to find out what the best ad balance is for his site.